# Styling created div's from a csv file using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, csv

I'm loading some columns from a csv file using php.

I am using divs to display the columns, but the issue is that the contents of the div for each heading is not perfectly aligned underneath the heading.

this is my php code:

```
<?php

    $file_handle = fopen("myCSV.csv", "r");

    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        //print '<tr>';
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        print "<div style='float:left; margin-right:15px;'>".$line_of_text[2].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$line_of_text[3].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$line_of_text[4].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$line_of_text[5].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$line_of_text[6].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$line_of_text[7].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$line_of_text[8].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$line_of_text[9]."</div><br /> ";
    }

    fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

How can I align the columns under each related headings properly?

here is the output data:

http://jsfiddle.net/w9v5q8vp/

This is how I tried to use a table:

```
print "<table>\n";
print "<tr><td>".$line_of_text[2]."</td></tr><tr><td>".$line_of_text[3]."</td></tr>";
print '</table>';
```

Comment: This is not related to PHP. Everything that deals with what you SEE in your browser is css/html. Your PHP code only generates the output, which is html/css. Put your output in http://jsfiddle.net and explain what you would like to get (instead of what you already got).

Comment: @Dekel, here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w9v5q8vp/

Comment: you're trying to display tabular data, so just use a `<table>`. that's what they're for.

Comment: You've probably heard someone say that tables are awful to use in HTML, but actually, they're only bad practice if you're using them to create your page's layout. CSVs contain tabular data, so it would probably be easiest and make the most sense to use a table.

Comment: I did try to use table but everything went all over the place to be honest and that is why i started using divs..

Comment: Show your table-based code and we will check what went wrong there.

Comment: @Dekel, please view my last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you output a table you should loop only over the rows:

```
$file_handle = fopen("myCSV.csv", "r");

print "<table>\n";
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    //print '<tr>';
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    print "<tr><td>".$line_of_text[2].'</td><td>'.$line_of_text[3].'</td><td>'.$line_of_text[4].'</td><td>'.$line_of_text[5].'</td><td>'.$line_of_text[6].'</td><td>'.$line_of_text[7].'</td><td>'.$line_of_text[8].'</td><td>'.$line_of_text[9]."</td></tr>\n";
}
print '</table>';
fclose($file_handle);
```

The beginning/end `table` tags should be printed only once.
You can read more about [table](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) [tr](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp) [td](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp) tags at w3schools.